# Way to force Chrome to use <title> tag data instead of writing address?

Tags: google-chrome, title

Is there a way to force Google Chrome to use the `<title>` tag data instead of writing the web page address?

Eg. `<title>&nbsp;</title>` is ignored by Chrome and the browser writes "[domain].com/index.html" on the tab instead of the expected space. The problem occurs whether I use an actual space or the HTML character code.  Other major browsers correctly read the title data as a space.

So does anyone know if there are any other invisible characters that Chrome will actually "display"?  I've tried a number of other &nb__; characters to no avail. I'm looking for an HTML solution if possible, because I access this site on a number of computers and I won't be able to install extensions in every situation.

And before I get any flack about having a blank title, this is a personal website I made for my own use, so I'm not worried about accessibility or other user's experience, just my own.  I recently switched from Firefox to Chrome and this is really bugging me.